# perl5.8 parse excel file with ParseExcel-0.59

Tags: excel, perl

Could you please help on this problem when I use perl module ParseExcel-0.59 to parse excel in Russia? I import cell format unicode map CP1251 which can parse Russia but there is warning like below:

Character in 'c' format wrapped in pack at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 1789.

Character in 'c' format wrapped in pack at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 1790.

the code is like this:

```
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new(); 
my $fmt = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::FmtUnicode->new(Unicode_Map => 'CP1251' );
my $wrkbooks = $parser->Parse('russia2.xls', $fmt);
```

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=376038

Comment: thanks for your help. I checked it seems the recipe in perlmonk couldn't solve my problem. thanks.

Comment: what does "I import cell format unicode map CP1251" mean?  can you show some code, please?

Comment: thanks. of course. the code is like this: my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new(); my $fmt = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::FmtUnicode->new(Unicode_Map => 'CP1251' );my $wrkbooks = $parser->Parse('russia2.xls', $fmt);

Comment: Probably related RT ticket: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=7376

Comment: Perl 5.8 is over a decade old, and it looks like [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) is up to 0.65 now. I would recommend upgrading the software you're using.